Cartoon show where a woman and some teenagers travel to a different world using a glove
I don't know if this was a fever dream. I used to watch this show as a toddler/kid, but can't remember the name. I do remember some things from it.
Plot I guess (based on remembering): A woman (I think she was a gardener or a teacher or both) and some teenagers go to a different world by using a glove I think to go there and said a certain words) to defeat the bad guys. They had wings on them as well, if remember right.
The TV show looked like it was made in the same era as Jem and the Holograms or the 70's
I can only remember two episodes of it and some scenes:
Episode 1: in this episode, it was a ski trip or something and two of the teenagers were racing or showing off (two boys I think). One of them caused their friend (a girl) to get injured because of it. Later in the episode, she was in a room in the different world by herself in sadness and pain. One of the henchmen of the bad guy came to her convince her to go to the bad guy and he will have her arm fixed unless she joins them, which she didn't. She defeated them and escaped. (That is what I remember of it or some parts.)
Episode 2: the teenagers were playing around in the woman's place and decided to go in her house and play around. The same girl decided to put on the glove and say the words that the lady would say to go to the other world. At first, they thought that it didn't work for them to go in without the woman there and just laughed it off. But then it glowed and teleported them to the world and they found that she was there, but her glove was on the girl at the time. (Can't remember much of this episode.)

In roughly which year did you watch this?

This is Sky Dancers (1996).
From Wikipedia:

The series follows five students at the High Hope Dance Academy under Queen Skyla, who work to defend the kingdom from her brother-in-law Sky Clone. Sky Clone killed his brother Skyler, Skyla's husband, as revenge for him being selected as king over him, but was unable to gain control of the Sky Swirl Stone, which gave the Sky Dancers their powers.

The protagonists are Jade, Camille, Breeze, Angelica and Slam, five young students attending High Hope Dance Academy. They discover that the headmistress, Dame Skyla, is secretly also Queen Skyla, ruler of a sky kingdom called the Wingdom. She asks the students to help defend the Wingdom from the show's main antagonist, Sky Clone, and gives them magic feathers that allow them to transform into winged superheroes called Sky Dancers. She also has a glove with the magical Sky Swirl Stone on it that can open a portal to the Wingdom when she utters the phrase: "If it is to be, it's up to me."


Sky Dancers - S01E01 - "The Sky's the Limit"

In episode 9, "Spread Your Wings," Angelica breaks her arm during a skiing trip and suffers a resulting crisis of confidence. Sky Clone's underlings learn of this and try to further undermine her confidence in hopes that she'll quit the Sky Dancers.
In episode 13, "Time and Again," Angelica finds Skyla's glove unattended in her home at the academy and inadvertently uses it to transport herself and the other Sky Dancers to the Wingdom's past.




I never would have guessed...
